# nginx shutting down because of fastcgi_keep_conn

Tags: nginx

I am having a weird problem with nginx configuration.

The server doesn't boot if I don't comment this line in nginx.conf

```
 #fastcgi_keep_conn on;
```

And it is uncommented everytime(overwritten) nginx crashes or if the system reboots

I am not sure if I am missing that module or if I have to install additional packages. Could someone point out the error?

Error in /var/log.nginx/nginx.log

```
unknown directive "fastcgi_keep_conn" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:29
```

Comment: What's in the error_log?

Comment: What nginx version do you use?

Comment: @VBart  nginx version: nginx/1.0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fastcgi_keep_conn` directive [appeared in nginx version 1.1.4](http://nginx.org/r/fastcgi_keep_conn) (released 20 Sep 2011). So your nginx version is too old, and doesn't support keepalive connections, as well cannot know about the directive.

Please, also note that your nginx [is obsolete and not supported](http://nginx.org/en/download.html).  You should update it ASAP.